Fibered product of schemes locally of finite type over a field is smooth if and only if its factors are smooth.
Let $X$ and $Y$ be $k$-schemes locally of finite type. Suppose their product $X \times_k Y$ is smooth at a point $z$ which projects to $x \in X$. I want to show that $X$ is smooth at $x$.
So far, I have noted that for schemes locally of finite type over a field, smoothness is the same as being geometrically regular. So here I have that $(X \times_k \overline{k}) \times (Y \times_k \overline{k})$ is regular, and I would like to show the two factors are regular. I am not sure how to proceed. Is this a good approach?

I like your idea of reducing to the case that $k$ is algebraically closed.
We can also reduce further to assume $z$ a closed point. Indeed, $X \times_k Y(k) \to X(k)$ is surjective, and to show $X$ is regular, it suffices to only consider closed points.
But then the Zariski tangent space satisfies $$T_{z} (X \times_k Y) \cong T_x X \oplus T_y Y $$ where $x, y$ are the respective projections of $z$. The dimension on the left side of the above is minimal so the dimensions on the right side have to be as well. Hence, $X$ is regular at $x$ and $Y$ is regular at $y$.
EDIT: We can reduce to the case that $X \times_k Y$ (and hence also $X$ and $Y$) is irreducible.
If $X \times_k Y$ is reducible and regular, it is disconnected. Hence, $X$ or $Y$ must be disconnected, say $X = X_1 \sqcup X_2$, so $X$ is regular iff $X_1$ and $X_2$ are regular, and $X \times_k Y = (X_1 \times_k Y) \sqcup (X_2 \times_k Y)$. As such, we're reduced to considering the cases of $(X_1 \times_k Y)$ and $(X_2 \times_k Y)$. We conclude by induction on components.

In order to make this argument it seems I would need to prove that the dimension of $\mathcal{O}{X \times_k Y, z}$ is the sum of the dimensions of $\mathcal{O}{X, x}$ and $\mathcal{O}_{Y, y}$. Is this true? How would I show such a thing?

@JackGallahan It is true. If $S$ is a scheme and $p \in S$ is a point, then $\operatorname{dim} \mathcal{O}_{S, p} = \operatorname{codim}_S(\overline{{p}})$.

Okay let me see if I can understand how that gets me there. Thank you very much for the help Daniel.

No problem. Let me know if it’s not clear. Note also that I’m using that these are all closed points.

I understand of course if X and Y are irreducible, then the codim of a closed point is just the dimension, and thus I can use the fact that dim(X) + dim(Y) = dim(X x Y) to show that $\mathrm{dim} (\mathcal{O}{X \times_k Y, z}) = \mathrm{dim}(\mathcal{O}{X, x}) + \mathrm{dim}(\mathcal{O}_{Y, y})$. How does this work when X and Y are not irreducible?

I also get that $\mathrm{dim}\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is the local dimension at $x$, i.e. the infimum of the dimensions of open neighborhoods of $x$. I just am not sure how to show that the local dimension of $X \times_k Y$ at $z$ is the sum of the local dimensions of X and Y at x and y, respectively.

@JackGallahan If you assume $X \times_k Y$ is irreducible (you can zoom in to ensure this is the case, since we’re assuming it’s smooth) then this should be okay, since the projection maps are surjective. I agree that this is a bit of a subtlety so I’ll edit when I get the chance.

Okay, thank you! Also, I don't understand how to reduce to the case that z is a closed point, because I am not trying to show that if the product is smooth everywhere, the factors are smooth everywhere. I only know the product is smooth at an arbitrary point.

@JackGallahan That's why I mentioned that the map of $k$ points is surjective. Pick an arbitrary $x \in X(k)$ and lift it to $z \in X \times_k Y$. Then, running the above argument shows that $X$ is regular at $x$.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
